# How can I set a cookie to a variable with javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

How can I set a JavaScript cookie to an already-defined variable *WITHOUT* using PHP?
My current code is this:

```
document.cookie = "cookieName=varName";
```

but that obviously does not work.
Thank you in advance!

I can't find anything else on any sites where I've looked, like https://developer.mozilla.org and https://w3schools.com, and also on stack overflow. There were many things about setting a pre-defined variable to a pre-defined variable, though.

EDIT: To clarify, I did find one duplicate of this question but could not really understand the answers. Please do not mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: You can try to update it's value with setCookie('cookieName',newValue) by checking whether it exists or not. If not, then try to set the cookie in usual manner

Comment: But how can I use the variable to set it? I know how to set the cookie normally but I want to find out how to set it so that it is based off of the variable. The variable is based off of an HTML input tag.